# how to use two arguments in python input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

this is my code :

```
name=input('whats your name? ')
print('ok', name,'lest go')
speak=input(name, '=>')
```

and this is my error

```
whats your name? hossein
ok hossein lest go
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hossein/Desktop/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    speak=input(name, '=>')
TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument, got 2
```

why i cant use `name` in input and how i can fix it.i want it to be like  `speak=input(name, '=>')` ==> `hossein =>`

thanks

Comment: concatenation of strings in python is done by using `+` not `,`

Comment: @maha yes thanks.it solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do `speak = input(name + " =>")` - the variable and string will be concatenated.

Comment: thanks @ObsoleteAwareProduce.your answer solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

The  ***input([prompt])*** function only accepts one argument. If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.
But you can concatenate the string you want in the input for example:

```py
>>> s = input('--> ')  
--> Monty Python's Flying Circus
>>> s  
"Monty Python's Flying Circus"
```

or

```py
>>> s2 = input('--> ' + s + '-')  
--> Monty Python's Flying Circus -
>>> s2  
"Monty Python's Flying Circus - My new input"
```